# convert vector of char to an int

Tags: c++, vector, char

I need to convert a part of `vector`s of `char`s to an `int`.
If I have

```
std::vector<char> // which contains something like asdf1234dsdsd
```

and I want to take characters from the 4th till 7th position and convert it into an int.
The positions are always known.

How do I do it the fastest way ?

I tried to use global copy and got a weird answer. Instead of 2 I got 48.

Comment: You could always do something like `std::stoi (std::string (std::begin (vec) + 4, std::begin (vec) + 8));` in C++11. It does involve creating that string, though.

Comment: are these positions known a priori (i.e. are they always literally 4 and 7) or do you have to find the number in the sequence first?

Comment: Yes the positions are always known

Comment: also, you're talking about 2 and 48, so you want the digits 1,2,3,4 not the whole number 1234, don't you? Anyway, you should present your code.

Comment: no the aim is to get into 1 int the value of 1234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the positions are known, you can do it like this

```
int x = (c[4] - '0') * 1000 + (c[5] - '0') * 100 + (c[6] - '0') * 10 + c[7] - '0';
```

Comment: Is it a faster way than convert it into a string and then atoi it ?

Comment: yes, this is as fast as you can get when you know the actual positions 4..7

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly flexible, although it doesn't check for overflow or anything fancy like that:

```
#include <algorithm>

int base10_digits(int a, char b) {
    return 10 * a + (b - '0');
}

int result = std::accumulate(myvec.begin()+4, myvec.begin()+8, 0, base10_digits);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason copying didn't work is probably because of endianness, assuming the first `char` is the most significant:

```
int x = (int(c[4]) << 24) + (int(c[5]) << 16) + (int(c[6]) << 8) + c[7]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't/can't use shiftting in this app.

Comment: you mean `(c[4] - '0') * 1000` etc?

Comment: Is it a faster way than convert it into a string and then atoi it ?

Comment: you concluded endianness issues from 'Big' in his nickname?

Comment: @unkulunkulu No, I'm assuming he want to treat the 4 8 bit chars as a 32 bit int.

Comment: I don't want the code will be assuming about the size of an int. It can be either 32/64 bits

Comment: @BigLeonardo, then you can use `sizeof` and write a loop.

Answer (score 1):

1.Take the address of the begin and end (one past the end) index.

2.Construct a std::string from it.

3.Feed it into a std::istringstream.

4.Extract the integer from the stringstream into a variable.

(This may be a bad idea!)

Comment: Can you code it ? What does it mean "this may be a bad idea" ? about what ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int vtoi(vector<char> vec, int beg, int end) // vector to int
{
  int ret = 0;
  int mult = pow(10 , (end-beg));

  for(int i = beg; i <= end; i++) {
    ret += (vec[i] - '0') * mult;
    mult /= 10;
  }
  return ret;
}

#define pb push_back

int main() {
  vector<char> vec;
  vec.pb('1');
  vec.pb('0');
  vec.pb('3');
  vec.pb('4');

  cout << vtoi(vec, 0, 3) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long res = 0;

for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
{
     res += vec[i] * pow (2, 8*(vec.size() - i - 1)); // 8 means number of bits in byte
}
```